# Highcharts - Redraw empty chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a rendered [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) chart on a website and I need to empty it after a certain time. Now I tried that with such code but the chart doesn't empty itself/nothing changes...

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
// Chart settings
});

// Some other JS
function emptyChart(chart) {
    chart.series = [];
    chart.redraw();
}

// Some code and a function executes this function after some time
emptyChart(chart);
```

I also don't get any error in the Firebug console or somewhere else, just nothing happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem already a second time and now I finally found a simple but currently only-working solution: Just create a new, empty Highchart:

```
function emptyChart(chart) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(/* chartOptions */);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A clean way to do this :

```
function emptyChart(chart) {
    while(chart.series.length !=0) {
        chart.series[0].hide();
        chart.series[0].remove();
    }
}
```

If you want your axis to disappear as well, use the "showEmpty: false" option (check [xAxis.showEmpty](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showEmpty) )

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you want something like this,

```
chart.series[0].data = [];
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: I want to clear the whole chart :) This also doesn't take any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try changing to `chart.series = {};`?

Comment: Then I get this error (via console): `a.series.push is not a function` and `chart.series` is a array[] which contains objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use setData([])

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()